# Run Script on reboot (Linux) in specific conda env

Tags: linux, cron, conda

I wanted to re-run my training (model), if my system restarts.
For that, I tried using crontab.

```
@reboot conda deactivate 
@reboot conda activate pytorch
@reboot bash scripts/train.sh
```

I added conda deactivate because it was opening with base.
But this didn't work out because I guess these are all run separately.
How can I set the environment for my scrip to run on reboot.

Comment: is it cron for the proper user? if yes, it should be on one line (separated by && ) and you'll probably need to source .bashrc or .bash_profile first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `conda run`**. The `conda activate` command is only intended for interactive shell sessions. For programmatic execution in an environment, Conda provides the `conda run` command. Try something like:

```bash
@reboot conda run -n pytorch . scripts/train.sh
```